# Can you use custom JavaScript with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I’m fairly new to bootstrap and had a question. Are you able to use custom JavaScript with bootstrap buttons without any special accommodations?

Comment: Yes. Yes, you can.

Comment: The bootstrap documents even show you how to use your own script for various component interactions

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely use custom JavaScript on top of Bootstrap's default scripts.

You'll want to keep your custom script(s) in a separate file to **[Bootstrap's JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/)**, remembering that external files are loaded from top-to-bottom, and that you'll need to load **[jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/)** before loading Bootstrap's JavaScript.

Simply include your own JavaScript files after you load Bootstrap's JavaScript file to have your changes override those introduced by Bootstrap:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom_script_1.js"></script>
<script src="custom_script_2.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you! So to clarify, does it require that you use jquery or will JavaScript alone be compatible with objects such as buttons?

Comment: **Everything** that jQuery can do can be done in vanilla JavaScript; regular JavaScript can manipulate Bootstrap buttons. jQuery is simply required for Bootstrap, because *they* choose to use some of jQuery's functions, meaning you can't run Bootstrap's JavaScript without also loading jQuery first.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, all the functions will work as with normal buttons.